# How to get a process tree trace/log of a process in linux?

Tags: linux, ps, strace

I want to know what executables a script launches and in what order (and trace those executables recursively).

For example, let's say I have a bash script here (called abc.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
gcc
```

I'd like to run this script with a "trace/log command" and get something like this:

```
abc.sh -- ls
      |-- gcc -- cpp
              -- cc1
              ... etc.
```

This show that abc.sh called ls, and gcc. gcc, in turn, called cpp and cc1.

Is this possible? How can I do it? A tree view like the above would be nice, but a simpler view would work as well.

Note that I do not want the current snapshot of the process tree. Rather, I want a trace or a log of the spawning processes. Timing annotation would also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to analyse the output of `strace` command.
Particularly, you'll be interested in something like

```
strace -f -tt -e trace=execve ./abc.sh
```

Comment: You probably want to tack on some output redirection and a grep so that you just get the exec part of the output. Particularly if the script you're tracing has output: strace -f  -e trace=execve ./t.sh 2>&1 | grep exec

Comment: This, this will work I think. 

I was hoping of some higher level script/tool that will do the following:
1. If there are commands other than execve that can spawn children, catch those as well.
2. Present it in a nice tree form.
3. Not print the unsuccessful execve commands (normally it goes through your entire PATH to see if the exe is present there).

Comment: @Paul: I'd rather use -o option to redirect strace output to a file. Cause nothing prevents the program to print something containing "exec" to stderr, right?

Comment: @madiyaan: you may also want to track fork/vfork/clone calls which lead to creating of new processes, but in fact execve is a signle syscall which leads to execution of a new program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pstree command. It was conceived to show exactly what you are looking for: process tree (hence the name, pstree). It won't give you process tracing, but you could call it multiple times to get something similar to what you're looking fOr.

Comment: What if the process spawns and exits very quickly?